# I'm getting this error while setting up MongoDB : String indices must be integers

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I don't know why this problem is only happening with me, most of my friends were able to run and use MongoDB without any interruptions using the same code. any help would be appreciated, Here's the code :

```py
dab = (os.getenv('cluster'))['discord']
collection = dab['toggle']
```

Comment: `os.getenv()` returns the value of an environment variable, which is a string. What are you expecting to get with `['discord']`?

Comment: discord is the name of the database in MongoDB and toggle is the collection name @Barmar

Comment: @BuddyBobIII I get this error : "String indices must be integers"

Comment: Ok now what happens when you print just `os.getenv('cluster')`

Comment: have you stored these in environment? try to print them first then you will get clear idea

Comment: `os.getenv()` doesn't return a MongoDB database, it returns a string from the environment. Why are you treating it as a dictionary?

Comment: Use `print(os.getenv('cluster'))`

Comment: It returns the mongo url

Comment: Do you mean "object is not **sub**scriptable"?

Comment: nah nah my bad I wrote the wrong message in the wrong place lol

Comment: If it returns a URL, you presunably need to fetch something from that URL, then parse it (as JSON probably), and *then* you can access keys like `discord`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [motor](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial-asyncio.html) which is an async wrapper for mongodb! Heres a basic example on how to insert and find a document

```py
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
#creating your client
db = AsyncIOMotorClient("connection uri")

#insert one
await db.my_database.my_collection.insert_one(mydocument)

#finding one
document = await db.my_database.my_collection.find_one({"somekey": value})
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response, after fixing the "string indices must be integers" error, another one popped up, and I tried doing this and it worked! + I had to update dnspython to the 2.1.0

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Start debugging:

1. Print the output you are getting from this

   os.getenv('cluster')

does it match with the output you are expecting?
if yes check the type of it (usually it would be string) the cause of the error

```
string indices must be integer
```

convert it to JSON format so u can get the value of ['discord'] from it

or u need to connect to the database first using the MongoClient(URL)

hope it helps u to figure out the reason why it is causing the error

Comment: if it worked nice! just upvote the answer so it help others